# Javascript: Async behavior in regex exec

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to execute a regex in a loop and I get strange results. For

```
var a = [], r = /(.*)\.\$\.(.*)/g, s = 'text.$.text';
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     a.push(r.exec(s + i));
}
console.log(a);
```

I get

```
[Array[3], null, Array[3], null, Array[3], null, Array[3], null, Array[3], null]
```

For

```
var a = [], r = /t/g, s = 'text.$.text';
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     a.push(r.exec(s + i));
} console.log(a);
```

I get

```
[Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], null, Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], null]
```

It seems like a timing problem. My first thought was that `//g.exec()` runs asynchronous and the complexer the regex is the more loop passes are to fast to execute the regex. But I can't find informations about this behaviour. What's happening here?

Comment: No, regex is not asynchronous at all.

Comment: Then why is this strange behaviour?

Comment: See the duplicate. Every time you get `null`, the end of the input was reached.